# Capture Explorer Filelist dropped on exe

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I'm building a file tool in VB.Net WinForms VS2010 and I would like to allow the user to select multiple files in Windows Explorer and drag/drop them on my exe. Is this even possible?

I have the code working for a drop on the open form. But need to figure out if I can get the object dropped on the EXE.

```
Private Sub frmDragDrop_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim returnValue As String()
    returnValue = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    If returnValue.Length > 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show(returnValue(1).ToString()) ' just shows first file from WE
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing")
    End If
End Sub
```

This works OK (not a complete example, other settings on the form needed):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles lstFromList.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        Dim MyFiles() As String
        Dim i As Integer
        ' Assign the files to an array.
        MyFiles = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop)
        ' Loop through the array and add the files to the list.
        For i = 0 To MyFiles.Length - 1
            If IO.Directory.Exists(MyFiles(i)) Then
                MyFiles(i) &= " <DIR>"
            End If
            lstFromList.Items.Add(MyFiles(i))
        Next
        RefeshCounts()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is easy:

```
Private Sub frmDragDrop_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sARGS As String()
    sARGS = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
    If sARGS.Length > 0 Then
        For Each s In sARGS
            TextBox1.AppendText(s & vbCrLf)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Not all the args() files, the first one or two are overhead.

If anyone knows how to use Debug with the code above please let me know! i.e. Can you somehow have VS2010 pass the same args() to a program run in the IDE?

Comment: You can: in the project settings | Debug tab, set "Command line arguments".

Comment: Note that the first item in the array is simply the path to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick tip for a smoother debugging experience:

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim commandLineArgs() As String

#If Not Debug Then
        commandLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
#Else
        commandLineArgs = "/fake/path/for/debugging/myApp.exe".Split()
#End If

        For Each argument As String In commandLineArgs
            Console.WriteLine(argument)
        Next
    End Sub
```